# Laravel DB::raw returning - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Why do I get this error?
The SQL works fine when I run it in phpMyAdmin.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select id from users where active = true and birthyear != 0000 and not exists (select id from agestats where users.id = agestats.user_id and agestats.year = 2020-01-13)

SQL:

```
select id
from users
where active = true
  and birthyear != 0000
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from agestats
    where users.id = agestats.user_id
      and agestats.year = 2020
  )
```

And the Laravel code:

```
$membersToInsert = DB::select(DB::raw(
  'select id
  from users
  where active = true
    and birthyear != 0000
    and not exists (
      select id
      from agestats
      where users.id = agestats.user_id
        and agestats.year = ' . date('Y-m-d')
));
```

Comment: 1. Line breaks and indentation are your friend, especially when you are asking people to read your code. 2. `date('Y-m-d')` will be `2020-01-13`, not `2020`. 3. Date strings need to be quoted. 4. Line breaks like I've introduced will make error messages MUCH more relevant.

Comment: Ouch, I should have seen that myself. I was so sure that the code have been working before. But offcourse it could'nt have done that. Thank you! And thank you also for giving me a heads up about correct writing. I will be better if there will be more posts. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date('Y-m-d')` will give you current date like `2020-01-13` so to get just `2020` then use `date('Y')`. I hope this helps your situation

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!